# Apache ignite failed to deserialize object

Tags: java, serialization, ignite, tomcat8

Environment :

- Tomcat8
- Ignite 2.11.1
- JDK 11 (corretto)

After some time on tomcat8 the web application user Ignite to handle http session do that kind of error. Always on the same type. But it works at the begining.

SequenceEditableList class inherite of Arraylist<>

```
   Caused by: org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to deserialize object with given class loader: [clsLdr=ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: xxxxxx
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@4277127c
, err=Failed to deserialize object [typeName=com.xxxx.web.common.list.SequenceEditableList]]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedMarshaller.unmarshal0(OptimizedMarshaller.java:261)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedMarshaller.unmarshal0(OptimizedMarshaller.java:225)
        at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:92)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadOptimized(BinaryUtils.java:1816)
        ... 137 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to deserialize object [typeName=com.xxxx.web.common.list.SequenceEditableList]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectInputStream.readObject0(OptimizedObjectInputStream.java:357)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectInputStream.readObjectOverride(OptimizedObjectInputStream.java:205)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:484)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:451)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedMarshaller.unmarshal0(OptimizedMarshaller.java:251)
        ... 140 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectInputStream.readSerializable(OptimizedObjectInputStream.java:611)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedClassDescriptor.read(OptimizedClassDescriptor.java:985)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectInputStream.readObject0(OptimizedObjectInputStream.java:353)
        ... 144 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor169.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectInputStream.readSerializable(OptimizedObjectInputStream.java:608)
        ... 146 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: filter status: REJECTED
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.filterCheck(ObjectInputStream.java:1356)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.checkArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1386)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:924)
        ... 150 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that your class loader rejects the class `SequenceEditableList`.

The class is rejected because of [serialization filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/serialization/filters/serialization-filtering.html). This mechanism is there to protect from many serialization vulnerabilities that caused problems in Java since the dawn of time.

The fix would be to find if your application already sets `jdk.serialFilter` system property anywhere. Ignite doesn't do that but maybe the application code or Tomcat do. Judging from the error, there must be this property somewhere.

When you've found where the property is defined, add your class to the allowed patterns. Like:

```
-Djdk.serialFilter=...;com.xxxx.web.common.list.SequenceEditableList
```

There aren't many details in the question, so it's hard to tell why it works in the beginning but fails after some time. Most likely it's because the classes are being deserialized in a different route (by a different class loader), or there just isn't an instance of `SequenceEditableList` that you need to deserialize. You could analyze.

Comment: Thank for your response. I think that is a very good analyze. So they were two 'routes' to serialize this class. And I reworked code to have only one, I still had errors, less.

Comment: In second time because I think that is inheritance from Arraylist (because ignite serialize lot of our class and that the only class with that inheritance), I reworked SequenceEditableList to implement List with ArrayList composition. This is in test.

Comment: For now rework ArrayList inheritance seems to solve this issue.